# How to get node by ID in Jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have created a jstree and i have a problem with getting node by id  of jstree.
when i use get_node, i get an error:

> TypeError: $(...).jstree.get_node is not a function

this is html code:

```
<div style="height: 75%; margin: 0; width: 100%;">
                    <div id="dashboardTree" style="border: 0; height: 99%; margin: 0; margin-top: 2px; overflow: auto; width: 99%;">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

this is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
initDashboardArchiveTree();//Initial tree
var node = $('#dashboardTree').jstree(true).get_node('1')//get that error
});
```

How to get node by id in jsTree?What's wrong with this code?

Comment: please post your initDashboardArchiveTree code as full as possible

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
var node = $('#dashboardTree').jstree(true).get_node('1, true')
```

New addition: `true`

**OR**

Change this:

```
var node = $('#dashboardTree').jstree(true).get_node('//something')
```

To this:

```
var node = $('#dashboardTree').jstree(true).find('//something');
```

---

Get the JSON of the parent and find the children.

Read the documentation on [jstree/JSON](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data).

Comment: How to find that node is disabled or not using get_node()??

Answer (score 8):

To get the node use this:
`$('#dashboardTree').jstree(true).get_node('1');`

If you need the actual DOM node, use this:
`$('#dashboardTree').jstree(true).get_node('1', true);`

But only invoke this once the tree is ready:

```
$('#dashboardTree').on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
  var node = data.instance.get_node('1');
})
initDashboardArchiveTree(); //Initial tree
```

Comment: your project saved the world alooooot of timeeeeeeeeeeee.( thank you * 10000000) times sir for that first class tree.

Answer (score 1):

should help this one:

```
.on("hover_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    let node_id = data.node.id
    let block   = data.instance.get_node(node_id, true)
...
```